# Alerting admins when certain fields are changed via profile & checksum?

Tags: profile, duplicate-contacts, checksum

Drupal 7, CiviCRM 5.10

I'd like to send out an "update details" email to contacts - a profile with checksum. It will include some other custom field questions but i want to be alerted specifically if the general contact fields are updated - Address, phone number etc.

I can put those who completed the profile into a group but that won't distinguish between those changed and those whose contact details remain the same..

I don't think i can create a duplicate to dedupe later if using checksum?

The only other idea i had is to have two profiles - one for my custom field questions and another for "change contact details" and rely on contacts only submitting that form if things have been altered - Even then it would be useful to know which field specifically had changed but perhaps that's my only option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have hosting that allows you to turn on [Detailed Logging](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/change-logging/#detailed-logging), there are two extensions that provide address history.  One is in Extended Reports; the other is Joseph Lacey's [Address Log](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/com.thenewpress.report.addresslog) report.  It should be relatively simple to extend either one to support phone/email/etc.

Another option, low-tech but effective, would be to export the contact details ahead of time, then export again after folks have filled things out.  Paste the two spreadsheets into one and use a simple formula.  E.g. if old email is in column C and new email in column H, `=IF(C1 != H1, "Changed", "")` in a new column will label any records where the email changed.

Comment: Thanks, i'll check those out. I have actually managed to go this long without being aware of detailed logging at all and combined with the address log report i think i should be able to get something that does what i need, pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve your goal using webforms. It may require a bit of jquery or could possibly be done just with Conditionals. I suspect the latter would require a read-only field 'showing' the data, and another field for the change. Then a conditional that says eg 'if A != B then set value to 'insert email address'. then set up a mailing on that basis.

i am possibly oversimplifying this but would be a route i would check.